# Is there a way to completely turn off sound in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Sometimes I like to play Fallout Shelter without any sound. At the same time, I do not really want to fully turn down my multi-media volume, for example if I want to listen to music at the same time, or if I just like the setting where it is, and I don't want to keep changing it every time I go into Fallout Shelter.

Inside Fallout Shelter, there are two volume sliders: one for sound and one for music. Unfortunately, there are quite a few sounds that do not seem to heed those settings, for example:

- The slide changing noise when the game starts
- The sound from the storage room robot
- The radio room
- The garden room

Is there any way to mute all sounds in the game, without muting the global phone settings?

Comment: Personally I'd regard this as a bug. Turning down sounds should turn down the sounds, all of them. Of course music is a separate category, but perhaps submit a bug to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Android, the two slider bars are successful in stopping all sounds. I did as you suggested and zoomed all the way in, clicking on various things, Mr. Handy, other dwellers, etc.  It sounds like a bug for that platform.

[image: Fallout Shelter Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mute your phones global settings, you have to turn both volume sliders down all the way or to where you want it. This worked on my vault so it should work for you. When you switch apps the music might stop playing so you should probably use earbuds, headphones or something similar.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't work. As I mentioned in my question some sounds continue even if both sliders are turned all the way down. Try zooming in on the fully upgraded storage room robot to see what I mean!

Comment: Oh. That's wierd.